# JAVA: split on pipe and append the values to string

Tags: java, string, replace, split

Need Suggestion to handle this in better way ?

I have data stored as TAX|CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 | SCHOOL, NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1 where TAX,CHURCH, SCHOOL are code which i'm not interested but their value.

```
if (input != null && !"NOTFOUND".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
    String[] list_str = input.split("\\|");
    int list_length = list_str.length;
    int i;

    for (String asset : list_str) {
        System.out.println(" asset : " + asset);
        if (asset.contains("TAX")) {
            /* get values for "TAX" */
            /* replace "TAX" from values */
        }

        if (asset.contains("CHURCH")) {
            input = input.replaceFirst("CHURCH", "");
        }

        if (asset.contains("SCHOOL")) {
            input = input.replaceAll("SCHOOL", "");
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(" input : " + input); /* final input */
```

**Input Condition:**

My input string may look like =
  "TAX|CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 | SCHOOL, NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1"
**or** "CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 | SCHOOL, NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1"
**or**  "TAX|CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00"
**or**  "CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00"

i am getting final input as "**,Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 | , NEVADA, Park-, 122.1**" but i am expecting my final string to be

input = "**Texas, San Antonia, 250.00, NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1**"

Comment: These specifications are really vague. Are the `CHURCH` and `SCHOOL` values you want to get rid of always followed by a comma? Where is the `TAX`?

Comment: remove all `(SCHOOL|CHURCH|TAX), ` and replace ` | ` by `, `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input format is guaranteed to be one of the formats you mention, the following code will work:

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "TAX|CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 | SCHOOL, NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1";
    String[] parts = input.split(" \\| ");
    String result = parts[0].split("CHURCH, ")[1];

    if (parts.length > 1) {
        result += ", " + parts[1].substring(8); 
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}

}
```

This splits the whole expression into two parts using a regular expression to check for the string `|`, a separate regular expression to get everything beyond the `CHURCH,` in the first part and if the second part of the expression is present, it uses a hardcoded index to get the substring you require, since the second part always starts with `SCHOOL,`

I would suggest reading up on regular expressions which can be very useful in this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1):

I just add the spaces Like this:

```
    String input = "CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 | SCHOOL, NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1";
    String i = "";
    if (input != null && !"NOTFOUND".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {

        String[] list_str = input.split(" \\| ");

        for (String asset : list_str) {
            System.out.println(asset);
            i = i + asset+" ";
            if (asset.contains("TAX")) {
                /* get values for "TAX" */
                /* replace "TAX" from values */
            }

            if (input.contains("CHURCH,")) {
                i =  i.replaceFirst("CHURCH,", "");
            }

            if (input.contains(" SCHOOL,")) {
                i =  i.replaceAll(" SCHOOL,", "");
            }


        }

    }
    System.out.println(" input : " + i); /* final input */
```

Comment: this doesn't solve Park-,problem. It removes every SCHOOL word from the string, I'm only interested to remove the first word after pipe ( | ) and i should be just "SCHOOL"

Comment: No , it's not, the output is `"input :  Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1"` , it will remove `school` which have spaces after it , any way http://stackoverflow.com/a/15670100/1743852 try this answer i think it's what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String input = "CHURCH, Texas, San Antonia, 250.00 | SCHOOL, NEVADA, Park-SCHOOL, 122.1";

if (input != null && !"NOTFOUND".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
    String[] list_str = input.split("\\|");

    for (String asset : list_str) {
        System.out.println(" asset : " + asset);
        if (asset.contains("TAX")) {
            /* get values for "TAX" */
        /* replace "TAX" from values */
        }

        if (asset.contains("CHURCH")) {
            input = input.replaceFirst("CHURCH,", "");
        }

        if (asset.contains("SCHOOL")) {
            input = input.replaceFirst("SCHOOL", "");
        }
    }
    input = input.replaceAll(" \\| ", "");
}

System.out.println(" input : " + input); /* final input */
```